# The mean deviation of a function on independent trials

Tags: summation

I have a function f(x).

I do M runs and M tends to infinity. For each run, I generate two random samples from the domain of f and calculate the square of the deviation.

The image might help clarify.

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTwx9.jpg)

What I have found is that the integral/sum over the uncorrelated, independent deviations adds up to 0. An explanation of why this is would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What is $a$ used for in the summation?  Do you mean $i_a$ and $j_a$ for the two samples?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry, I missed that